# validation page in prestashop is blank after confirm payment

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I have prestashop 1.6.0.9 running. All was well when suddenly after i wanted to test the order of a product, the last page validation, after confirming the order is blank. I used the modules bank wire and cash on delivery and with every module is returning the white page. I tried uninstalling this modules, delete them and then re-install but this didn't help. I wouldn't want to reinstall prestashop again and I wonder if there is a solution for this problem...

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn debug mode on (true) in

*config/defines.inc.php*

and change line

`define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);` to `define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);`

This will show any errors instead of blank white pages. Post here Your error and we will try to help.